# Viewing a deleted *flagged* question

Tags: support, feature-request, flags, deleted-answers

I know I don't have the privilege to view a deleted question but recently I flagged a question that I believed was spam.

[image: Flagged Answer]

The reviewer obviously had an objection, which is fine, but I wanted to see and learn from my mistake. I am normally careful with the spam flag and as my first declined spam flag I thought it might be helpful to see if I had made a mistake.

Is there, or should there be, a way to see deleted questions/answers that you have flagged.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can only see deleted posts if:

1. You have link (which you do in this case)

and

2. You have over 10k reputation (which you don't)

or

3. You created the post (which you didn't).

So while it would be nice if you could go back and review the post I don't think that this is going to be implemented.

In this case I can see why you flagged it as spam, but it looks like the "answer" was just a "thank you" post in French despite containing a link. Though on further consideration it probably is spam.

Comment: Should I have flagged it as not an answer, I seem to remember the link going to some unrelated site. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Let me disagree with you and with Jon who handled that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31599711/578411). That link goes directly to a site where you can buy stuff. The posts only goal is to get that link turn up in google...

Comment: @rene, that's just it; I'm not looking to have the decline vote reversed, the answer was deleted, but I wanted to see if it was a valid flag. I guess I could just ask here though.

Comment: @hoss It's clearly spam: It's an automated "thank you" message that could apply to about any subject, followed by a link to locksmith services. These guys are huge spammers in France.

Comment: @hoss You flagged correctly. I'm afraid for some reason I can't fathom out I declined it incorrectly. So my apologies and if you do see posts like that in the future, then yes, please do spam flag them.

Answer (score 18):

There's a workaround if you haven't got 10k yet - you can hover the link and see the text of the post in the popup. No images though :(

Comment: Nice. I didn't know. Now I'm hovering through recent deleted posts and I can see enough of the content to remember why I've flagged them.

Comment: Wait, *what*? I have thousands of flags and I (used to) check flag history obsessively, and I've never seen this feature. Why is SE UI so unintuitive!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Chrome v44 on Fedora 22 Linux. There is no title attribute on the link, so I can't see how this would work.

Comment: This does not work for me as well.  Chrome v44 windows 7 pro

Comment: @Tiny: It works for me on Chrome v44, but only for questions. Not answers.

Comment: @Lightness I stand corrected. It does work on questions, but not on answers.